# Convertir script en .exe python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bueno amigos el hecho es que me estoy iniciando en esto de la programación aprendiendo python. Y he buscado información acerca de como volver tu sript ejecutable en un ordenador donde no tenga el interpetre instalado. Ya he leído que para eso se convierte el archivo a un .exe pero no me queda del todo claro como es el proceso. Podrían indicar me que librería se utiliza para esto o como es el proceso ? Y que sea ejecutable tanto en win,mac y linux . Lo que quiero convertir es una aplicación de consola . y utilizo python 3.

Comment: El problema de eso es que necesitas compilar una versión para cada sistema operativo y arquitectura al igual que harías con lenguajes compilados. El 'exe' para Windows no va a funcionar en Debian y viceversa.En plataformas *nix no suele tener esto mucho sentido ya que muchas de ellas traen el intérprete ya instalado y si no, es muy simple instalarlo.Al compilar pierdes una de las gracias de los lenguajes interpretados; mismo código para todas las plataformas. No obstante poder se puede, mirate [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) o [cx_freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla tu sabes si al tener dependencias de archivos en mi código (e.g. cargar CSV o exportar xlsx) puedo usar  PyInstaller? Por otro lado, tengo archivos que se actualizan día a día (se reemplaza el CSV de ayer por el de hoy tienen igual nombre) se podrá realizar esta actualización de archivos para ejecutar el .exe?

Comment: @JorgePonti se pueden incluir bibliotecas externas pero no todas son soportadas.  No se si usas Pandas o openpyxl, no se si será posible con ellas o que problemas pueden dar. En lo personal no soy partidario de estas herramientas (solo en casos muy concretos las veo útiles). Si se va a usar un programa a menudo en un PC lo lógico es instalar el intérprete. En cuanto a lo de lanzar el exe cuando se actualice el csv, o se llama al exe o script mediante el mismo mecanismo que actualiza o necesitas un proceso en segundo plano que lo lance cuando encuentre que ha sido modificado el archivo.

Comment: @FJSevilla lo intentaré el fin de semana. Tengo el archivo .py en un servidor, un compañero intentó correr el programa desde su casa en un computador a través de escritorio remoto, pero no se pudo. A pesar que el servidor tenga instalado el interprete, al ejecutarlo como escritorio remoto, el PC que lo realiza igual debe tener instalado el interprete? Gracias.

Comment: @JorgePonti si el script se ejecuta en el servidor solo el servidor necesita el intérprete. Cualquiera con los permisos adecuados  puede ejecutar el script  en el servidor desde escritorio remoto, desde ssh, etc. Solo neceitas el intéprete en el sistema que ejecuta el script,. Otra cosa es que alguien se conecte al servidor, se descargue el script en  su sistema e intente ejecutarlo en sus sistema. Si lo que intentó es ejecutar el script en el servidor posiblemente fuera problemas de permisos aunque es difícil suponer algo sin saber más. Si tienes más dudas contacta por el chat , un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu consulta apunta a lo que se conoce como "freeze" o congelado de aplicaciones, es básicamente una forma de distribuir tu programa junto con las dependencias más un interprete **python** también con todas sus dependencias. Este proceso normalmente crea una carpeta, un zip o incluso un exe, en teoría con todo lo que necesita tu aplicación para ejecutarse de forma totalmente independiente y "portable". Este proceso nunca es multiplataforma, es decir: para hacer una distribución para Linux, necesitas un Linux + Python + una herramienta de freeze que corra bajo este SO, igual que con el resto de los sistemas operativos. En definitiva, lo métodos tradicionales de distribución mediante el código fuente suelen ser mucho más cómodos en este sentido, sin embargo tanto Win con Mac son SOs dónde no podemos asumir que tenemos **python** instalado, en Linux te diría que casí seguro todas las distros cuentan con el interprete, pero seguramente no todas con las últimas versiones.

### ¿Que opciones para distribución tenemos?

**[Cx_freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**: Permite ejecutarse en los tres SOs y por consiguiente armar las distribuciones correspondientes. Puede generar una carpeta con un ejecutable y todas las dependencias. Soporta desde la versión 2.7 del interprete en adelante.

**[pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)**: De igual forma que la anterior, corre en los principales SOs. Bajo Windows tiene la posibilidad de crear un EXE único con todos los scripts, dependencias e interprete dentro de él, y automáticamente luego se descomprime todo en una carpeta temporal y se ejecuta de manera transparente. Es compatible con las versiones 2.7 y 3.3-3.5 del interprete.

**[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)**: Ha quedado un poco atrás con respecto a las anteriores herramientas ya que solo apunto a los entornos Windows.

En general, todas estas herramientas tienen una forma de trabajar sencilla  o avanzada. En el primer caso, por ejemplo con **[pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)**, podrías hacer simplemente (bajo win) `pyinstaller miapp.py --onefile` y obtendrías un `miapp.exe` con todo incluído. Este modo simple obviamente funciona con requerimientos sencillos y scripts simples, para cosas más avanzadas hay que configurar todo mediante algún script, en el caso de **[Cx_freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**, usa el típico setup.py que usa la distutils, en el otro caso, hay que crear un archivo de especificaciones  pero en ambos casos no dejan de ser scripts de **python**, mediante estos archivos podremos configurar cosas como, la inclusión de iconos, gráficos, archivos de datos, dependencias no reconocidas, o simplemente definir el icono de nuestro programa.